AsyncValue.guard results with AsyncLoading
I have a riverpod provider which stuck in the AsyncLoading state for weird reason. Should be AsyncData after AsyncValue.guard, but stays in AsyncLoading state indefinitely
@riverpod
class SelectedAccount extends _$SelectedAccount {
  // ignore: avoid_public_notifier_properties
  late final logger = ref.read(loggerProvider("logger_tag"));

  @override
  FutureOr<Account> build() async => Future.any([]);

  Future<void> select(AccountSearchRecord account) async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    logger.info("selecting $account");
    logger.info("state $state"); // prints "state AsyncLoading<Account>()"

    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      final response = await ref.read(accountProvider(id: account.id).future);
      logger.info("$response"); // prints successful response 
      return response;
    });
    logger.info("state $state"); // prints "state AsyncLoading<Account>()" again
  }
}


Do you mean the AsyncLoadingState does not change after calling select(...)?

@DanR that's correct

For testing, could you print a message when build is called?

How do you know that the last state AsyncLoading<Account>() print was from the logger.info call from the last line? Can you change the word used in the string? Also, can you show the code on how you use this selectedAccountProvider?

But where do you change the state in the guard method ? your "response" object is an Account object? if it is not , that's the problem.

Try this:
@riverpod
class SelectedAccount extends _$SelectedAccount {
  // ignore: avoid_public_notifier_properties
  late final logger = ref.read(loggerProvider("logger_tag"));

  @override
  FutureOr<Account> build() async => Future.any([]);

  Future<void> select(AccountSearchRecord account) async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    logger.info("selecting $account");
    logger.info("state $state");

      final response = await ref.read(accountProvider(id: account.id).future);
      logger.info("$response"); 
    state = await AsyncValue.data(response);
    logger.info("state $state"); 

      }
}

